# Android not booting on Virtualbox

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, virtualbox

Im trying to use android on Virtualbox. 4.3. I downloaded an iso, and used [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/) to help me download it. After following all the steps, it told me to remove the iso from the machine which i did. Now it shows [this](http://prntscr.com/6oppz8) over and over again.

Comment: What are your machine's specs?  Do you have virtualization enabled?  Do you have any other virtual machine programs/services like vmWare or HAXM installed?

Comment: I use virtualbox only. 3gb ram, 286 gb hard drive, intel core 2 duo p8700 2.53 ghz win7  home premium 32bit @MatthewRead

Comment: That is very little RAM for running a VM, I would suspect that as the issue.  Even with more RAM you can expect very poor performance with that processor as well.

Comment: mk. thanks a lot. I was able to wing it in windows xp, since, well, it's XP. lmao @MatthewRead Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed the same tutorial and got to where you are. It took about two minutes of just letting it run before I got to the welcome screen. Are you absolutely sure you're stuck?
[image: welcome screen]

Comment: Mine ran infinitely long, stuck on the cool-looking android logo, freezing every min or so.